# How to set action of a notification?

Tags: android

So I made an app where the user can create notifications as reminders. The notification pops up and works, but I want to delete the notification when the user clicks an action. Here is my code:

```
            Intent intent =  new Intent();
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,0,intent,0);

            Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notification))
                    .setOngoing(switchState)
                    .setContentTitle("Noteify")
                    .setContentText(notifEditText.getText().toString())
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.delete,"Delete",pIntent)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();


            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            nm.notify(0,notif);
```

I added the action, but I don't know how to actually delete the notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, simply call this:

```
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Below this

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("MyApp")
    .setContentText(message)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(icon);
```

Comment: Try this let me know

Answer (score 0):

Gowthaman M said is correct, Add `setAutoCancel(true);` to `Notification` object.

Just edit your code as below,

```
        Intent intent =  new Intent();
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this,0,intent,0);

        Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notification))
            .setOngoing(switchState)
            .setContentTitle("Noteify")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(notifEditText.getText().toString())
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .addAction(R.drawable.delete, "Delete", pIntent)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();


        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(0,notif);
```